# TObjectList and destructor custom class

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

i use custom class TFrame in TObjectList. TFrame contain ListBoxItem and record's. 
Еheir parent can only be TListBox.

```
  TFrame = class
    ListboxItem: TListBoxItem;
    Name: string;
    PosStart,
    PosEnd : integer;
    Max: TData;
    Min: TData;
    Sqrt: TData;
    constructor Create (ListBox: TListBox);
    destructor Destroy;
  end;

destructor TFrame.Destroy;
  begin
    ListboxItem.destroy;
  end;
```

how to write a destructor for correct deletion with ObjectList.Delete(i)? 
Now if ill try to delete - i have visible items with exception message.

Ty much!

Comment: What exception exactly? Please provide a [mcve] and the complete error message

Answer (score 3):

Your destructor needs to override the base class destructor

```
destructor Destroy; override;
```

Otherwise it won't be called by `Free`.

And you should also call the inherited destructor.

```
destructor TFrame.Destroy;
begin
  ListboxItem.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Also, use `Free` rather than calling a destructor directly so that your code is protected against `nil` references.

There may well be other bugs in the code we can't see.